# What is a reasonable size of a contours vector (openCV)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm trying to track a small object with OpenCV and a Basler Camera (resolution 492 x 658), but i get undefined Behavior when I run the code and i think it might have something to do with the contours.

I'm using `findContours()`. The object I'm tracking is approx `15 x 15 pixels`. The size I get for the biggest contours vector is around `500000000`. This seems to be too big.

When i use `canny` before `findContours` the size gets reduced to `170000000`. Which is a bit smaller but still appears to be too big.

What would be a reasonable size of a contour vector tracking a 15 x 15 pixel object?

Platform: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Why don't you show the image after findContours() to see the contours yourself rather than only the size of them?

Comment: contours is a vector <vector <point>> how can i show this with opencv?

Comment: Yes you can use cv::drawContours which can take your vector of vectors and draw it on input image

Comment: ok. i solved the problem by installing opencv again. I have no Idea why it didn't work before. The size of the biggest contour vector now is around 25.